# Структура базы данных для авто

Tags: mysql, база-данных, проектирование

Допустим на сайте будут автомобили, некоторые из которых будут электромобили.
Т.е. будет марка авто одна на все типы авто, но модели и характеристики должны отличаться для каждого типа авто(для электромобилей дополнительные характеристики).
Как организовать такую базу?
Предполагаю, что должна быть общая таблица на все типы авто: `cars` с полями `id, mark, price`, а в таблице характеристик будут такие поля: `id, cars_id, model, params, type`.
Или должна быть отдельная таблица для электромобилей с характеристиками?
Посоветуйте пожалуйста, как это организовать.
С базами ещё мало работал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно все зависит от того что должно в конце получится.
Можно так:

```
cars [ 
    car_id, 
    mark_id, 
    model_id, 
    type_id, 
    category_id,
    color_id, 
    transmission_id,
    mileage,  
    year of manufacture, 
    ... 
]

cars_marks [mark_id, name, ...]

cars_types [type_id, name, ...]

cars_models[model_id, name, ...]

cars_categories[category_Id, name, ...]

cars_colors[color_Id, name, ...]

cars_transmissions[ transmission_id, name, ...]
```

специфические атрибуты, вынесети в отдельную таблицу, например так

```
cars_custom_field[ custom_field_id, name, field_value_type_id, ... ] //дополнительные характеристики

cars_custom_field_types[ field_value_type_id, name ] //типы возвращаемых значений

cars_types_custom_fields[ car_type_id, field_id ] //связки типа авто с характеристикой

cars_details[ car_id, custom_field_id, value ] //значения дополнительных характеристик
```

поля params лучше не делать, а разносить параметры по разным столбцам

Comment: подскажите, в вашем примере в какой таблице хранить цену, а в какой характеристику? с помощью `inner join` объединили 4 таблицы, и как выбирать потом нужную информацию к примеру для электромобиля?

Comment: На счет цены - ее лучше хранить в отдельной таблице,т.к. цена в разный момент времени у одной машины может быть разная. На машины могут быть специальные предложения и т. д. Так же цена зависит от комплектации авто(двигатель, цвет, материал салона, коврики) и.т.д. Поэтому как правило есть базовая цена авто и отдельно цены по опциям. Какие свойства отнести к базовой комплектации а какие к опциям - это вопрос.  Чтобы точно определиться со структурой, надо точно знать что вы хотите в итоге получить.

Comment: По поводу отбора - отбираете по type_id, например так: `select * from cars where type_id = 2`, join для этого не нужен.

Comment: подскажите, `select * from cars where type_id = 2` этот запрос вернёт данные без модели, марки. Смысл в данном запросе, который вернёт только id на таблицы? т.е. меня интересует то, как правильно обращаться к данным, формировать выборку, не совсем понял смысл данного запроса без `join`

Comment: На чем будете писать приложение? Какие фрэймворки и технологии  использовать? Все ORM фрэймворки сами генерят простые запросы к БД.

Comment: на laravel буду делать

Comment: В вашем примере, надо сначала делать выборку по типу потом left join

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, как и в каких таблицах всё-таки правильно разместить параметры для разных категорий автомобилей (т.е. для электромобилей характеристики будут отличаться от обычных авто)

Comment: в базе нужно хранить два типа автомобилей (обычные авто и электромобили). У электромобилей могут быть дополнительные характеристики, которых нет у обычных автомобилей

Comment: Все зависит от того на сколько разные у них характеристики, от их общего количества и вероятности роста числа характеристик в будущем. А есть списки характеристик? где их можно посмотреть?

Comment: допустим у автомобилей и электромобилей есть общие характеристики: пробег, год, цвет, коробка передач, а есть и разные: у электромобилей  `Пробег на заряде`. Как организовать такую структуру подскажите пожалуйста. Нашёл статьи в которых советуют применять модель eav(сущность-атрибут-значение). Покажите пожалуйста, хотя-бы вкратце, как в вашем ответе, какие таблицы должны быть для таких связей. Как в таблице можно различать что авто является электромобилем, и как создать вышеприведённые характеристики подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: и если ещё должны быть категории, допустим "авто из Европы, авто из США", эти категории можно ли организовать вместе с характеристиками (таксономиями) или для категорий нужна другая таблица?

Comment: проектированием ещё не занимался, хочется понять, как организовать такую сложную структуру, чтобы был шаблон

Comment: есть марки и модель авто, а также тип(электромобили, обычные авто), характеристики(цвет,год, пробег на заряде) и категории (авто из Европы,США). Подскажите пожалуйста, как это всё организовать?

Comment: поставлю вам лайки в других ваших ответах

Comment: категории и характеристики динамические, т.е. могут постоянно добавляться

Comment: @word я дополнил ответ

Comment: благодарю, объясните пожалуйста, как функционируют эти таблицы: `cars_custom_field, cars_custom_field_types, cars_types_custom_fields, cars_details`. не совсем понял их назначение и связи в них. И объясните пожалуйста, для чего создавать отдельную таблицу к примеру эту `cars_colors` для цвета? Еще не понял смысл в этом, в будущем это как-то облегчит работу с цветом?

Comment: список всех характеристик храните в таблице cars_custom_field, т.к. у характеристик значения могут быть разных тип( строка, число, и т.д.) каждому полю, надо прописать какой тип значения оно содержит. Соответственно список всех возможных типов значений значений можно хранить в отдельной таблице cars_custom_field_types. В таблице cars_types_custom_fields храните связи типов автомобилей и характеристик. Это позволит отбирать список характеристик в зависимости от типа авто. А в таблице cars_details храните непосредственно данные хпрактеристик каждой машины.